# jQuery + CSS: How to detect the first "move out" of cursor out of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do the same as does Twitter -- when you click on the Follow button, then is added there the class called **cancel-hover-style**. When you move the cursor out of this button, the CSS class **cancel-hover-style** is removed.

How to detect this "first move out"?

Thank you

Comment: use ``mouseleave`` or ``mouseout`` event

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at the events section of the JQuery documentation

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: please don't forget to mark an answer if any of the solutions provided helped solve your problem. Also, I would personally like to see how you used the information provided here or elsewhere to solve this issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `on`/`off`. jQuery has a built-in solution for this.

Use [`jQuery.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). It will only execute the handler once.

You can use this to listen for the first (and only first) `mouseout` event, and remove whatever CSS class you're interested in removing.

```
elem.one("mouseout",  function() { $(this).removeClass("hoverClass"); })
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery, these are probably all the events you will need to accomplish this, modified to your specific logic requirements of course.

```
elem.on("mouseover", function() { $(this).addClass("hoverClass"); });
elem.on("mouseout",  function() { $(this).removeClass("hoverClass"); })
elem.on("mousedown", function() { $(this).addClass("clickClass"); });
elem.on("mouseup",   function() { $(this).removeClass("clickClass"); })
```

to remove the event handler for a specific event, in a handler add

```
$(this).off("eventName");
```

and to control specific parts of the process, make each peice a different handler function and then you can use

```
$(this).off("eventName"[, selector, handler]);
```

where both the selector and handler are optional parameters.

**UPDATE**

In light of information provided by another answer here, I agree that my examples can be simplified for this particular case by using .one() instead of .on(). In fact, a perfect fit for the requirements

Comment: haha, thank you @epascarello for pointing that out! That's what i get for not proofreading

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="">Follow</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {background: #298be6; color: #fff; display: inline-block; font-family: Helvetica; padding: 5px 20px; text-decoration: none;}

.cancel {background: #e64242;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('cancel').text('Unfollow');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('cancel').text('Follow');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/c3UYD/